# TypeError: Requested keys of a value that is not an object. React-native Listview

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting TypeError when i use  `<Listview />`. `Axios` is used for api request.
There are two components :

1. `<JsonHome />`
2. `<ListItem />`

`ListItem` is child component of `JsonHome`.

**JsonHome**

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true
        }
        this.goToDetail = this.goToDetail.bind(this);
        this.dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    data: res.data,
                });
            })
    }
    goToDetail(id) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', {
            id: id
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.itemList}>
                <ScrollView>
                    <ListView
                        dataSource={this.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.data)}
                        renderRow={(item) => <ListItem item={item} onTouch={this.goToDetail} />}
                    />
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

**ListItem**

```
const ListItem = (props) => {
    const item = props.item;
    return (
        <View style={styles.item} >
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.onTouch(item.id)}>
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>{`${item.id} ${item.title}`}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

**api response** :

```
[
 {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
 },
 {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
 }
]
```

Comment: So, whats is the problem?

Comment: i get this erro -> TypeError: Requested keys of a value that is not an object.

Comment: seems to be a problem of passing the props in listitem, can you create demo to produce the issue.

Comment: where  i can create demo.

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/ you can use this

Answer (score 0):

What version of react-native are you using?  According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview) `ListView` is deprecated in favor of using a `FlatList` for boosted performance.  I suspect ListView unable to extract a default value suitable for key use.  FlatList has most of the same props available to it, as well as a `keyExtractor` prop function if your data doesn't lend itself well to default keys.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    isLoading: true
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(res => this.setState({
     isLoading: false,
     data: res.data,
  });
}

goToDetail = (id) => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Detail', { id: id });
}

ListItem = ({ item, onTouch }) => (
  <View style={styles.item} >
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onTouch(item.id)}>
      <Text style={styles.itemText}>{`${item.id} ${item.title}`}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.itemList}>
      <ScrollView>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderRow={(item) => <ListItem item={item} onTouch={this.goToDetail} />}
        />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: but i want infinite scroll.

Comment: FlatList wraps a VirtualizedList, which I think can give you the "infinite" scrolling you seek.  Requires reading the docs and setting/using different props.

Comment: can you give example of VirtualizedList @DrewReese

Comment: Unfortunately, no, since I don't do much RN dev work.  But after a quick google search it seems the `FlatList` is optimized by default to give you this behavior, given your datasource is plays nicely with the optimization, i.e. it isn't mutating and returning an entirely new list each render cycle.  I found this [article](https://www.codementor.io/lsiden/getting-a-react-native-flatlist-to-be-performant-ik47nkj5q) helpful in explaining achieving a virtualized flat list.  If my answer helped you with your original question about the error I'd appreciate it being accepted.